# Python web scraping error: 'NoneType' object is not callable after using split function

Tags: python, web-scraping, split, nonetype

I'm a beginner writing my first scraping script trying to extract company name, phone number, and email from the following [page](http://pcoc.officialbuyersguide.net/Listing?MDSID=CPC-1210).

So far my script successfully pulls out the name and phone number, but I am getting stuck on pulling out the email, which is nested within a script object. My latest two attempts involved using regex, and when that failed, a split function, which is returning the error mentioned in the title.

Script:

```py
import re
import requests

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "http://pcoc.officialbuyersguide.net/Listing?MDSID=CPC-1210"
html = urlopen(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for company_name in soup.find_all(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(company_name.find('h1').text)

for phone in soup.find_all(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(phone.find(class_='Disappear').text)

for email in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(email.find('script').text)
    print(email.split('LinkValue: "')[1].split('"')[0])
    print(re.findall(r"([\w\._]+\@([\w_]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)", soup))
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-ace5e5106ea7> in <module>
      1 for email in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
      2     print(email.find('script').text)
----> 3     print(email.split('LinkValue: "')[1].split('"')[0])
      4     print(re.findall(r"([\w\._]+\@([\w_]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)", soup))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

HTML within "script" that I'm trying to pull from:

`EMLink('com','aol','mikemhnam','<div class="emailgraphic"><img style="position: relative; top: 3px;" src="https://www.naylornetwork.com/EMailProtector/text-gif.aspx?sx=com&nx=mikemhnam&dx=aol&size=9&color=034af3&underline=yes" border=0></div>','pcoc.officialbuyersguide.net Inquiry','onClick=\'$.get("TrackLinkClick", { LinkType: "Email", LinkValue: "mikemhnam@aol.com", MDSID: "CPC-1210", AdListingID: "" });\'')`

Comment: Messing around with attributes to see if there's a potential route there and am getting "None" as a response to the following:  

```for email in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(email.find('script', attrs = {'LinkValue:'}))```

Comment: Are you sure that there's an element, which matches `ListingPageNameAddress`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, BeautifulSoup doesn't expose a `split` function on elements.

BeautifulSoup elements allow you to specify any attribute tough, and if it isn't a property or function of the element, it will look for a tag with that name. For instance,  `element.div` would find the first descendant of `element` that is a `div`. So you can even do things like `element.nonsense`, and since `nonsense` is not a function or property of the `element` object, it then searches the document tree for a descendant with the name `nonsense`, and since one doesn't exist, it will simply return `None`.

So when you call `email.split(...)`, it doesn't find a function or property called `split` on the `email` object, so it searches the HTML tree for a tag named `split`. Since it can't find an element named `split`, it returns `None`, and you try to call it as a function, which results in the error you are getting.

Is it possible you meant to get the text from email `email.text.split()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This might solve your problem.

```
import re
import requests

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "http://pcoc.officialbuyersguide.net/Listing?MDSID=CPC-1210"
html = urlopen(url1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for company_name in soup.find_all(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(company_name.find('h1').text)

for phone in soup.find_all(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(phone.find(class_='Disappear').text)

for email in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(email.find('script').text)
    a=email.find('script').text
#    print(email.split('LinkValue: "')[1].split('"')[0])
    print(str(re.findall(r"\S+@\S+", a)).split('"')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try str(email) before you split it? It worked for me!